# Помогите решить задачу в python

Tags: python

Вводятся целые числа в одну строчку через пробел. Необходимо преобразить эти данные в список целых чисел. Затем, перебрать этот список в цикле for и просуммировать все значения с нечетными индексами. Результат вывести на экран.
Пытался решить в одну строчку, но неверно. В строчке "1 2 3 4 5" нужно сложить 2+4, потому что питон считает индексы с нуля, а у меня складывает 1+3+5. Программу оставлю ниже

```py
print(sum([int(i) for i in input().split() if int(i) % 2 == 0]))
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Просто можно использовать не весь список, а его срез с установленым шагом `2`

```py
>>> a = "1 2 3 4 5"
>>> a.split()[1::2] 
['2', '4']
```

Здесь буквально: "взять срез с первого элемента включительно, до последнего элемента, с шагом два". И условие по индексу и лишние операции такие, как `%`-остаток от деления, не нужны.

А далее забрать сумму

```py
>>> sum([int(i) for i in a.split()[1::2]])
6
```

Тест

```
>>> sum([int(i) for i in input().split()[1::2]])
23 56 74 89 12 78
223
```

Comment: спасибо! возможно я был некорректен, но строчка "1 2 3 4 5" - условная строка. программа должна работать вне зависимости от того, какая это строчка. например " 23 56 74 89 12 78". тут должен будет сложить 56+89+78. строчку с цифрами задаем сами

Comment: @Evgeniy2 так, замените `a` на `input` и будет вам счастье. Добавил кастомную строку через `input` в ответ